# How to load nocache.js form html page other than default page?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, no-cache

I m developing a web application using GWT technology.
But i m facing the loading time problem in my application.It take about 1min 30sec to load.
This problem is being faced only when application loaded fist time on any browser.
It is found that maximum time is being taken by the all *.js being added to my project.
I want that my index.html must load first and than all other html and .js must load on any button click.
For that i want to load my nocache.js from page other than default html page of gwt project.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can load the gwt app under user request, adding some js code to your index.html and calling it from an html button:

```
  <script>
     function loadGWT() {
       var s = document.createElement('script');
       s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
       s.setAttribute('src',"mymodule.nocahe.js");
       document.body.appendChild(s);
     }
  </script>
  <button onClick='loadGWT()'>Load GWT App </button>
```

[edited]

You have to use `xsiframe` linker instead of the `standard` one. Add this line to your `.gwt.xml` file

```
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
```

Comment: That won't work out-of-the-box as the standard linker uses `document.write`. I think the `xsiframe` is OK, but maybe only if you enable some of its hidden features (can't remember, never used)

Comment: You are right std linker does not work, but xs and xsiframe work ok.